# how to trigger fromEvent() rxjs with button on click?

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, vue-rx

**What i want?**

Countdown when click play button

**Code**

I use vuejs and vuerx to do this. here my code

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      energy: 12
    }
  },
  domStreams: ["play$"],
  subscriptions() {
    const energy$ = Observable.interval(250)
    .fromEvent(play$, 'click')
    .startWith(this.energy)
    .scan(time => time - 1)
    .takeWhile(time => time > 0)
    return {
      energy$
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

my HTML

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="play$">Play</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="energy">
    <br>
    <h1>{{ energy$ }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Error message :

https://pastebin.com/umEYDejs

Comment: interval().fromEvent()... makes no sense, please refer to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Yeah i know. but when I switch that over, it says `play$ not reverenced during render. `

Comment: Have you find any solution for this ? am trying to use fromEvent in my vue component but it says that it's not a valid event

Comment: still dont find any man, and I dont find try it again @Rebolon